# How a rgb led panel ( 16x32) works?

Tags: led, led-driver, led-matrix

I'm currently working on a rgb led panel ( 16x32 1/4 scan rate ) ( driving with stm32f0)
But i couldnt really understand what do i need to do to light up a specific led.

When i apply one clock to R1 pin and latch it(suppose whole pannel lights are closed)
red lights are lighting up from right side of as you see below.
What do i need to do to light up only one single led. I read too much i check some arduino code. but totally failed.if i understand working principle then i think rest is easy.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Probably a good place to start would be https://learn.adafruit.com/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix

Comment: Which panel is that? Make, model, link to datasheet? The details are in the datasheet.

Comment: there is just a label on the board as p10rgb smd3535 1/4 ..

i checked all pages that i found.
situation is fail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to basically just excerpt from [Adafruit's learning page](https://learn.adafruit.com/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix) on this subject.

> Keep in mind that these displays are normally designed to be driven by FPGAs or other high speed processors; they do not have built in PWM control of any kind. Instead, you're supposed to redraw the screen over and over to 'manually' PWM the whole thing. On a 16 MHz Arduino, we managed to squeeze 12-bit color (4096 colors) but this display would really shine if driven by an FPGA, CPLD, Propeller, XMOS or other high speed multi-proc essor controller.

... and ...

> On most Arduino-compatible boards, you'll need 12 digital pins, and about 800 bytes of RAM to hold the 12-bit color image (double that for the 32x32 matrix, double again for smooth double-buffered animation).

The operating principle here is obviously not very simple by the looks of it, and you'd be much better off starting with some low-level libraries with graphics libraries built on top of them (as described in the link above). Trying to do this all from bare metal would be a fairly major undertaking.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. My point is little bit different as i think. Im trying to handle of printing only one single led. i dont want to drive led panel with full capacity. printing images,animations etc.. no need them. i just need to light up a single led.

Comment: You can dig into one of the graphics primitives to figure out how that works, at the link above click on library and notice this code: `matrix.drawPixel(0, 0, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 7));`